# elasticsearch high cpu usage every hourly

Tags: elasticsearch

we have 8 clustered nodes and each nodes have 1 replica. 
total document size is about 4GB and 1,984,173 docs.

I was suffering from very high CPU usage 80%~90% every hourly.
when I see bigdesk's graphs at this time,
cpu high, search queue high, gc high, load Average high,
search requests per second high ... everything high!
It is held for 5 min.

there is no other process except es on each server.
there is no other cron job even at that time.

I thought there are something wrong with es process.
maybe external attacks or gc problem.. I don't know.

It happened every hourly.
I don't know what's going on elasticsearch at this time!! 
somebody help me, tell me what happened in there. please..

```
$ ./elasticsearch -v 
Version: 1.4.2, Build: 927caff/2014-12-16T14:11:12Z, JVM: 1.7.0_75 

$ java -version 
java version "1.7.0_75" 
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_75-b13) 
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.75-b04, mixed mode)
```

and I installed plugins - HQ, bigdesk, head, kopf, sense

Comment: Have you checked logs of a node at that time? Do you maybe perform heavy indexing at that time or querying for statistics? You might need to add more information in your question like `_nodes/stats` or/and any cluster setting/configuration that might cause this

Comment: If there is nothing else happening  , there is a high probability that merge process is being executed at that point of time.

Comment: Basically, I'm facing the same problem right now. Meanwhile, I figured out that the problem is related to GC. A lot of data is moved into Old and causes FullGC. Still unable to find out why

Comment: I am facing the same problem, 
We can  solve it by avoiding the JVM process getting swapped to disk. On Server lock the process address space into RAM by setting bootstrap.mlockall=true in the Elasticsearch configuration file and the environment variable MAX_LOCKED_MEMORY=unlimited